# Работала слеш команда, а сейчас нет, в чем проблема?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдает вот такую ошибку. При этом при этом 5 минут назад все отлично работало, но после того как я написал пару строк появилась ошибка. Попытался понять в чем дело, но даже вернул в начальный вид и все равно ошибка, использовал другие файлы, где кода нету(ну только вызов бота и префикс) и там была эта же ошибка. При этом, если я уберу дополнительные переменные в скобках, то ошибки нету, а если точнее то работает, когда в скобках только 1 переменная. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Попробуйте написать вместо `текст` `content`

Comment: Все, починил, переустановил библиотеку discord.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! Просто переустановил библиотеку discord.py